# passing string to opencart using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I have an Opencart website, I am currently trying to use ajax at the frontend to pass data to php controller in the backend, but I am unable to get the value from the request in backend

here is the frontend ajax code:

```
$.ajax({    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/addAll',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_list= test' ,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(json) {});
```

at the backend controller, I am trying to retrieve variable "product_list" but it is not working

```
$products = $this->request->post['product_list'];
$logger->write("products to add to cart is"+ strval($products));
```

the last statement keeps printing 0 to the log file
any help with this ? what is wrong here?

I also tried

```
$products = json_decode($this->request->post['product_list'], true);
```

with same results

Comment: Can you try `data: {'product_list': 'test'}` on ajax

Comment: tried that, when using inspect option in chrome, it shows data passed like this  "{'product_list': 'test'}: "  and in backend, the validation (isset($this->request->post['product_list'])  fails

Comment: also if I passed a number like this "data: 'product_list= 10'"  it works perfectly, it seems the issue with passing characters

Comment: Do you tried like this: `data: "product_list='test'"`

Comment: yes and not working

Comment: Try by setting string to a variable(`var myString = 'test';`) & use `data: {'product_list': myString}`. Please check the data in console.

Comment: not working, in inspect/ network, the passed data is "{product_list: test}: " , so in the server side this check is failing "isset($this->request->post['product_list'])"

Comment: Ok,, fixed,  Ajax was not the issue, it was accessing the variable from server side, so I used $_POST instead of $this->request->post  and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed, Ajax was not the issue, it was accessing the variable from server side, so I used `$_POST` 
instead of `$this->request->post` and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

So I just did this

in file `catalog/view/theme/defaulttemplate/common/home.twig` I add this code at the end of the file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({url:'index.php?route=checkout/cart/addAll',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_list= test' ,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(json) {}
    });
});
```

and in file `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` on line 479 I add this

```php
    public function addAll(){

        print_r($this->request->post);
    }
```

And I see this in my console http://joxi.ru/krDlvPdfKGejar

All I did was correct your js code. hope this helps.